# Mongodb Interval Query

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb database with a collection user_arrival. The documents look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0431821d0f986bdb338e82"),
    "location" : {
        "uuid" : "b8e671f3-742e-4a24-ae3e-6cd543e7c5bb",
        "name" : "London"
    },
    "time" : ISODate("2019-12-16T16:37:45.000Z"),
    "actor" : {
        "user" : {
            "uuid" : "c42f7cbf-84a6-4912-b414-6afc873e229d",
            "name" : "User 1"
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0431d31d0f986bdb338e83"),
    "location" : {
        "uuid" : "b8e671f3-742e-4a24-ae3e-6cd543e7c5bb",
        "name" : "London"
    },
    "time" : ISODate("2019-12-16T17:00:00.000Z"),
    "actor" : {
        "user" : {
            "uuid" : "c42f7cbf-84a6-4912-b414-6afc873e229d",
            "name" : "User 1"
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0431e41d0f986bdb338e84"),
    "location" : {
        "uuid" : "b8e671f3-742e-4a24-ae3e-6cd543e7c5bb",
        "name" : "London"
    },
    "time" : ISODate("2019-12-16T17:05:00.000Z"),
    "actor" : {
        "user" : {
            "uuid" : "c42f7cbf-84a6-4912-b414-6afc873e229d",
            "name" : "User 1"
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e04320f1d0f986bdb338e85"),
    "location" : {
        "uuid" : "b8e671f3-742e-4a24-ae3e-6cd543e7c5bb",
        "name" : "London"
    },
    "time" : ISODate("2019-12-16T17:06:00.000Z"),
    "actor" : {
        "user" : {
            "uuid" : "d42f7cbf-84a6-4912-b414-6afc873e229d",
            "name" : "User 2"
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0432191d0f986bdb338e86"),
    "location" : {
        "uuid" : "b8e671f3-742e-4a24-ae3e-6cd543e7c5bb",
        "name" : "London"
    },
    "time" : ISODate("2019-12-16T17:15:00.000Z"),
    "actor" : {
        "user" : {
            "uuid" : "d42f7cbf-84a6-4912-b414-6afc873e229d",
            "name" : "User 2"
        }
    }
}
```

According to above documents

- User 1 - First-time card scan at 16:37:45
- User 1 - Second-time card scan at 17:00:00
- User 1 - Third-time card scan at 17:05:00
- User 2 - First-time card scan at 17:06:00
- User 2 - Second-time card scan at 17:15:00
  Mongodb Group Query

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        time: { $gt: new Date('2019-12-16T00:00:00.000Z'), $lte: new Date('2019-12-17T00:00:00.000Z') },
        'location.uuid': 'b8e671f3-742e-4a24-ae3e-6cd543e7c5bb',
    },
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            hour: { $hour: { date: '$time' } },
            minute: {
                $subtract: [
                    { $minute: { date: '$time'} },
                    { $mod: [{ $minute: '$time' }, 60] },
                ],
            },
        },
        count: { $addToSet: '$actor.user.uuid' },
    },
},
{
    $project: {
        start_time: { $add: ['$_id.hour', 0] },
        end_time: { $add: ['$_id.hour', 1] },
        total_user_arrivals: { $size: '$count' },
        _id: 0,
    },
},
])
```

When I execute the above MongoDB query below results get.

```
[{
    "start_time" : 16.0,
    "end_time" : 17.0,
    "total_user_arrivals" : 1
},
{
    "start_time" : 17.0,
    "end_time" : 18.0,
    "total_user_arrivals" : 2
}]
```

Expexted Result

- User 1 first-time card scan between 16:00:00 to 17:00:00
- User 2 first-time card scan between 17:00:00 to 18:00:00

```
[{
    "start_time" : 16.0,
    "end_time" : 17.0,
    "total_user_arrivals" : 1
},
{
    "start_time" : 17.0,
    "end_time" : 18.0,
    "total_user_arrivals" : 1
}]
```

Comment: Please share collection at https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before grouping, you need to get the first transaction of the users.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        time: { $gt: new Date('2019-12-16T00:00:00.000Z'), $lte: new Date('2019-12-17T00:00:00.000Z') },
        'location.uuid': 'b8e671f3-742e-4a24-ae3e-6cd543e7c5bb',
    },
},
{ $sort: { time: 1 } },
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            uuid: '$actor.user.uuid',
        },
        tran: { $first: '$$ROOT' },
    },
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            hour: { $hour: { date: '$tran.time' } },
            minute: {
                $subtract: [
                    { $minute: { date: '$tran.time'} },
                    { $mod: [{ $minute: '$tran.time' }, 60] },
                ],
            },
        },
        count: { $addToSet: '$tran.actor.user.uuid' },
    },
},
{
    $project: {
        start_time: { $add: ['$_id.hour', 0] },
        end_time: { $add: ['$_id.hour', 1] },
        total_user_arrivals: { $size: '$count' },
        _id: 0,
    },
},
])
```